# Testing links using rspec?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec

If I have something like `<%= link_to "Help", help_path %>` in the view file, how do I test the following using rspec?

1. It goes to `help_path`.
2. The content reads "Help".

I am currently using capybara.

---

edit

While answers below can work, I think I found a simpler way of doing this.

```
describe "some link on whatever page" do
  subject { page }
  before { visit whatever_path }
  it { should have_link('Help', href: help_path) }
end
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are using capybara then

```
my_link = find(:css, "a:contains('Help')")
my_link.click

and get page status, should be 200 or simply check


my_link.href
```

But also you could simply add routes specs to your integration specs in rspec. Like this to be always sure this routes exists

```
describe HelpController do

  it "should have proper routes" do
    {:get => "/halp/772/parser/18/edit" }.should be_routable
    {:post => "/halp/772/parser" }.should be_routable
    {:delete => "/halp/772/parser/18" }.should be_routable          
  end

end
```

Answer (score 2):

Your file could look like this:

```
require 'spec_helper'

feature "Help" do
  scenario "creation" do
    visit help_path                         # access your help path
    page.should have_content("Help")        # verify content
  end
end
```

If you need some help with testing with Capybara you could find some here:
  [Railscasts #257 Request Specs and Capybara](http://railscasts.com/episodes/257-request-specs-and-capybara)  or 
  [Capybara repo at Github](https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara)

Answer (score 2):

Use `have_tag` matcher. [Here](http://cheat.errtheblog.com/s/have_tag/) is a cheatsheet.

```
response.should have_tag("a[href$=#{help_path}]", :text => "Help")
```

P.S. Did you read [rails guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/testing.html#testing-views)?

Comment: have_tag is no longer valid. The cheatsheet link is dead. have_selector is probably the closest replacement. http://guides.rubyonrails.org/testing.html#testing-views

Answer (score 0):

`click_link "Help"`

Gist of a capybara cheatsheet: https://gist.github.com/zhengjia/428105